# Java applet won't load

Tags: java, browser, applet

I am building a small applet in java. It works fine (really!) when I run it in eclipse as an applet. Problems start when I export it as a jar and than try to load it through an html page.
Here's the html code:

```
<body>

<applet  archive="myJar.jar" width=650 height=850>

</applet>
</body>
```

Now when I run other jar files in this way they work fine, for example if you view the source page of this niffty [demo](http://niffty.sourceforge.net/example.html)

```
    <body>
    <applet code="org.niffty.Niffty.class" archive="niffty.jar" width=650 height=850>
    <param name="file" value="prelude.nif">
    </applet>
    </body>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `code` attribute in your `applet` tag. Without it, the browser doesn't know which class in your JAR file is the applet it should display.

Answer (score 2):

You've specified the archive, but no `code` attribute so the applet runner doesn't know which class to use as the entry point. You have to *either* specify `code` *or* specify the `object` attribute to give a serialized applet instance - but `code` is much more likely to be appropriate for you.

See the [documentation for the `applet` tag](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/applet.html) for more information.